# SQL Query Is Giving Wrong Output

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have three tables EMPLOYEE,EMPLOYEE_UNIT,UNIT
    i want employee details including name and employee unit names for single user based on employee_id(For example employee 1 is working for 2 different units..
    i want employee name with working units:

```
TABLE STRUCTURE AS FOLLOWS:
EMPLOYEE TABLE
EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER
1            emp1       emp1      ***********
2            emp2       emp2      ***********
3            emp3       emp3      ***********
4            emp4       emp4      *********** 
UNIT TABLE
UNIT_ID,UNIT_TITLE,CITY
1       unit1      city1
2       unit2      city2
3       unit3      city3

EMPLOYEE_UNIT TABLE
EMP_UNIT_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,UNIT_ID
1            1           2
2            1           3
3            2           1
```

MyQUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) AS TITLE,PHONE_NUMBER 
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT AS EU ON EU.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = 137
```

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" service. Please post the query you've tried and your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list of employee names and corresponding unit titles, use this:

```
SELECT e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.UNIT_TITLE SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT m ON e.EMPLOYEE_ID = m.EMP_ID
JOIN UNIT u ON m.UNIT_ID = u.UNIT_ID
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

MySQL has [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this type of thing.

Comment: i want employee units also......if 1 employee working for multiple units..thoose 2 suppose to come along with employee details

Comment: In the same record?

Comment: can u help me the query